# How to apply a Workbooks.Open() command to .csv files in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I’m listing all the .csv files in a directory, open them one by one and apply “Text To Columns”, then I save each file as .xlsx .
In order to open files I use:

```
Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
```

Where directory  is:

```
directory = wb.Sheets("Directory").Cells(1, 2).Value
```

and filename is a variable.

I’ve noticed: when a file is opened by `Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)` command, even before applying “Text to Columns” a .csv file shows it's content splitted in columns (instead of putting all content in one column).
Is there a way to define in `Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)` that any file must be opened as .csv?

Thanks

Comment: If the CSV-Files are saved as "*.csv" then you also could set the seperator by having the first line `SEP=,` to use "," as seperator or `SEP=;` for using ";"...

Answer (score 1):

Please try to follow the parameter as the link.
The key point is delimiter is , or ;

```
workbooks.Open(Filename, [UpdateLinks], [ReadOnly], [Format], [Password], [WriteResPassword], [IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended], [Origin], **[Delimiter]**, [Editable], [Notify], [Converter], [AddToMru], [Local], [CorruptLoad])
```

from [www.safaribooksonline.com](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-excel-with/0596007663/re315.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to read the data "as-is" from the text files, including csv, and write it to an Excel workbook:

```
Function MM_OpenTextFile(vPath As String, delim As String) As Variant 

    Dim FF As Integer 
    Dim lineArray As Variant 
    Dim temp As String 
    Dim arrayList As Object 

    Set arrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") 

    FF = FreeFile 

    Open vPath For Input As #FF 
    While Not EOF(FF) 
        Line Input #FF, temp 
        lineArray = Split(temp, delim) 
        arrayList.Add lineArray 
        Erase lineArray 
    Wend 
    Close #FF 

    MM_OpenTextFile = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrayList.ToArray())) 

    arrayList.Clear 

    Set arrayList = Nothing 

End Function
```

This will assign the contents of the delimited file as a 2D array to a variant, which can then be placed on a worksheet in it's delimited state like so:

```
Sub Example() 

    Dim ar As Variant '// Must be a Variant to work

    '// Change to a file and delimiter of your choosing...
    ar = MM_OpenTextFile("C:\Users\BloggsJ\SomeFile.txt", ";")          

    '// Change 'A1' to the cell you want the data pasting to 
    With Range("A1").Resize(UBound(ar, 1), UBound(ar, 2)) 
        .NumberFormat = "@" '// Change format to "text"
        .value = ar '// insert array values
    End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I have a doubt, if this code can be applicable to many files (in my directory i have about 500 .csv files with 10 rows and 10 columns of content)?

Comment: @KennethChan That would make absolutely no difference using the code in my answer.

Comment: @Ale I wouldn't advise trying to open 500 files at the same time - but you can use this code in a loop to open each one in sequence.

Comment: yes, i meant to open 500 files in a loop closing a file before passing to the next one

Comment: @Ale the function opens the file as a text file, and closes it again all within the function - it reads the text directly without having to open the file in Excel so it's much faster too.

Answer (score -1):

Issue is with your Windows setting, it is automatically splitting the words based on the list separator. You can change the list separtor setting in windows and try to open the csv as normal excel.

```
you can change the List separator setting in the Regional and Language Options as specified on the

    1.  Click the Windows Start menu.
    2.  Click Control Panel.
    3.  Open the Regional and Language Options dialog box.
    4.  Click the Regional Options Tab.
    5.  Click Customize / Additional settings (Win10).
    6.  Type a new separator in the List separator box.
    7.  Click OK twice.
```

Comment: I have an impression that the setting of delimiter can be set by MS Excel. Excel will memorized the user's option. Next time, MS Excel will directly apply the option instead.

Comment: if the windows have delimiter option, it will automatically delimit the data. I thought there could be an issue because of that.